# SSlError from concurrent s3 file download

Tags: python, ssl, amazon-s3, multiprocessing, boto

So I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix this bug....

Basically I have a program that downloads all of the files from an s3 bucket and parses through each file's contents and adds records to a database. Doing it sequentially is too slow, so I decided to try downloading and processing the files in parallel using the multiprocess module since the whole process doesn't need to have any sort of shared memory or locking system. Therefore I made my code look something like the following:

```
from multiprocess import Pool
import boto

def doWork(s3key):

    # connect to s3 bucket and get s3 file key
    conn = boto.connect_s3('aws_key_id', 'aws_secret_access_key')
    bucket = conn.get_bucket('my_bucket')
    key = bucket.get_key(s3key)

    ##########ERROR THROWN BY THIS CALL#####################
    key.get_contents_to_filename('my_file')

    # insert into database here....


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()

    # for every s3 file in bucket, download/process file in a parallel worker
    for s3keyname in s3keyname_list:
         pool.apply_async(doWork, s3keyname)
```

For some reason the call 'get_contents_to_filename()' raises an SSLError but only sometimes! Even weirder is that if I am downloading 7 files at once, only 1 file will not download correctly because the error is thrown in only one of the subprocesses. So sometimes all of the files download correctly, and others only one file throws an error. The error message says something about using the wrong version of ssl, but shouldn't trying to download the other files throw the same error as well? I've tried googling around, and the best I could find was maybe its some sort of buffer overflow issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you find any different result with using pool.map(function, interable)   for example   pool.map(doWork, [s3keyname])